# Knockout binding of a Dynamically generated Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have 2 Dropdownlists. Both are data-bound through knockout. I am trying to achive 2 things here: The first dropdown is *Certification*, the second dropdown is *Specialization*.

1. The second dropdown should by default have 'Please select Specialization' as an option which is not happening. It is happening for the first dropdown. I think I know why. Maybe it's because *Certification* is an observable array which is being data bound through the `options` binding.
2. Unfortunately I cannot do the same for the second dropdown, since its values are going to depend on the first dropdown. Even though I have given an `optionsCaption` for the second dropdown, I still don't see it when the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Provider = {
        ProviderID: ko.observable(""),
        FirstName: ko.observable(""),
        LastName: ko.observable(""),
        Certification: ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]),
        SelectedCertification: ko.observable(""),
        Specialization: ko.observable(""),
        TaxonomyCode: ko.observable(""),
        SSN: ko.observable(""),
        ContactNumber: ko.observable(""),
        ContactEmail: ko.observable(""),
        NPI: ko.observable("")
    };
    ko.applyBindings(Provider);

    $("#Certification").change(function () {
        if (($("#Certification").val() == "M.D.") || ($("#Certification").val() == "M.B.B.S")) {
            $("#Err_Certification").hide();
            $("#Certification").removeClass('borderclass');

            $("<option>Dermatology</option>").appendTo("#Specialization");
            $("<option>Hematology</option>").appendTo("#Specialization");
            $("<option>Neurology</option>").appendTo("#Specialization");
        } else if (($("#Certification").val() == "R.N.") || ($("#Certification").val() == "M.S.N.")) {
            $("#Err_Certification").hide();
            $("#Certification").removeClass('borderclass');
            //$("#Certification option[value='option1']").remove();
            //$("#Certification option[value='option2']").remove();
            //$("#Certification option[value='option3']").remove();

            $("<option>Pediatric Nursing</option>").appendTo("#Specialization");
            $("<option>Critical Care Nursing</option>").appendTo("#Specialization");
            $("<option>Occupational Health Nursing </option>").appendTo("#Specialization");
        } else {
            $("#Specialization").addClass('borderclass');
            $("#Err_Specialization").show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">CERTIFICATION:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="Certification" name="Certification" data-bind="value: SelectedCertification, options: Certification, optionsCaption: 'Select a Certification'">
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">SPECIALIZATION:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="Specialization" name="Specialization" data-bind="value: Specialization, optionsCaption: 'Select a Specialization'">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have cleaned up your post for you. Please don't post your code to external sites only, but include it in your question. Your first task will be to cut out *everything* that doesn't have to do anything with the problem you describe. Every library, every observable, anything that is not absolutely necessary to power two dropdown fields. You should end up with less than 20 lines of JS code and HTML that doesn't contain a lot more than 2 `<select>` elements.

Comment: Please don't roll back my edit. I made a substantial improvement to your question.

Comment: Posting all code you have does not help anybody. Once you've reduced your question scope to the minimum we can go on.

Comment: I have not posted my entire.Only the code related to the dropdowns.

Comment: well dont mix up code with jquery & ko . try to create a observable array for second dropdown options binding  and try  it works . sample http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22095/

Comment: Well,JS bin does provide an option separate them out and I had separated them.And it seems like your code is what I was looking for.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helps. well you can check below provided a answer to do it in clean ko way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got forked up the jquery change and some code and bringing in `subscribe` .

**View Model :**

```
  var Provider = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.Certification = ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]);
          self.SpecialzationArray = ko.observableArray();
          self.SelectedCertification = ko.observable();
          self.Specialization = ko.observable();
          self.SelectedCertification.subscribe(function (val) {
            self.SpecialzationArray([]);
              if (val == "M.D." || val == "M.B.B.S") {
                  self.SpecialzationArray(["Dermatology", "Hematology", "Neurology"])
              } else if (val == "R.N." || val == "M.S.N.") {
                  self.SpecialzationArray(["Pediatric Nursing", "Critical Care Nursing", "Occupational Health Nursing"])
              } else {
                  self.SpecialzationArray([]);
              }
          });

      };

      $(document).ready(function () {
          ko.applyBindings(new Provider());
      });
```

**View :**

```
<select data-bind="value: SelectedCertification, options: Certification, optionsCaption: 'Select a Certification'"></select>
<br/>
<select data-bind="value: Specialization,options:SpecialzationArray, optionsCaption: 'Select a Specialization'"></select>
```

When ever there is a  change in dropdownlist as i'm subscribing to `value` binding of DDL1 we can conditionally fill the data required for dropdown2 .

For Working fiddle **[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22098/)**

It's always better to maintain view model clean which helps when you dealing in complex scenarios .