# How to get change dropdown value using knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I use knockout subscribe function to get the selected value of the 1st dropdown and displays the record of 2nd dropdown. If i changed the dropdown list of 1st by using the

```
 $('#country').val(countryid);
$('#country').change();
```

this changes the value of the dropdown but it dosen't reflect the 2nd dropdown. As i googled i couldn't get an clear idea for the issue.

Any help appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you attach a Fiddle to show us some more please.

Comment: you are looking for cascading functionality i believe & if so you get lots of stuff in SO about that .

Comment: @Sander: I'm new to fiddle.. U can say at place u have doubts?

Comment: @supercool : IS there any specific link?

Comment: StackOverflow mate . further you can refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125955/knockout-binding-of-a-dynamically-generated-dropdown-options/28126533#28126533

Comment: @supercool: I use this method to bind my 2nd dropdown list. But my problem is that when i change the dropdown list by using the change method that self.whatever.subscribe(function(newValue){} ) is not getting invoked. I need solution for that problem.

Comment: may i know why you are trying mix things use `ko` way

Answer (score 0):

At last found the answer. 
`self.selectedcountry(value)` 
this will invoke the subscribe function when you try to change the value of the dropdown.